# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError: Operation timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, асинхронность, sequelize.js

Ошибка скрипта, я так понимаю, это ошибка из-за большого кол-ва запросов в бд.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError: Operation timeout

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'tradein',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectOptions: {
      connectTimeout: 60000
    },    
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      idle: 20000,
      acquire: 20000
    }
  },
  test: {
    username: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'trade',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectOptions: {
      connectTimeout: 60000
    },
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      idle: 20000,
      acquire: 20000
      }
  },
  production: {
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectOptions: {
      connectTimeout: 60000
    },
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      idle: 20000,
      acquire: 20000
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Так а вопрос тогда в чём? )

Comment: Покажите с какими настройками вы инициализируете библиотеку.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica обновил

Comment: Поменяйте значение `max` в `pool`. Сделайте `50` хотя бы.

Answer (score 0):

В целом да, обычно эта ошибка является результатом того, что не получилось получить подключение из пула для отправки запроса.

Когда вы `Sequelize` инициализируете, то что в настройках для `pool` передаёте?

По молчанию там:

```
{
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
}
```

Т.е, если у вас сейчас `5` соединений занято (выполняется 5 запросов), то при попытке выполнить шестой запрос, будет эта ошибка, т.к. нету свободных подключений в пуле.

Поднимите значение `max`.

Но такая ошибка, в частности, может говорить и о проблемах в запросах. Скажем, если у вас очень тяжёлый запрос, который долго выполняется, он будет удерживать соединение, так что никто больше им не сможет воспользоваться в этот момент. Если это так, то профилируйте ваши запросы (хотя это делать нужно в любом случае), чтобы выявить такие медленные запросы.

Comment: поставил 200 значение max и ошибка все равно

Comment: @ЭмильКулуев а ошибка сразу или после какого-то момента?

Comment: не сразу, почти минуту идут обращения в базу потом ошибка